Irreducible Representations of $SO(3)$ and Clebsch-Gordan Matrices - A concrete Example
The goal of this post is to understand the construction of $SO(3)$-equivariant functions using irreducible representations of $SO(3)$, as done in this paper. I want to understand it by (more or less) explicitly writing out a representation of $SO(3)$ via the action on polynomials of degree at most $2$. My main confusion so far is the definition/construction of Clebsch-Gordan matrices.
Disclaimer: I am not an algebraist, thus I may be unfamiliar with some commonly used notation in the field of representation theory; and may use some notation that is unusual, so brace yourselves.
To the best of my understanding, mainly based on this related post, we can get an irreducible representation $\rho_d:SO(3)\rightarrow GL(\mathbb R^{2d+1})$ by considering the action of $SO(3)$ on the space of homogeneous harmonic polynomials of degree $d$, i.e. a matrix $U$ transforming a polynomial $p$ by transforming it's input via $(U\cdot p)(x):=p(Ux)$. Now in the linked paper it is claimed, see Eq. (5), that we can write any representation $\rho$ of $SO(3)$ as $$\rho(U)=Q^T\bigg[\bigoplus_{J} D_J(U)\bigg]Q=Q^T\begin{pmatrix}D_0(U) & 0 & \dots &0 \\ 0 & D_1(U) & \dots  & 0 \\ \dots \\ 0 & 0 &\dots  &D_K(U)\end{pmatrix}Q.$$
In this setting, $D_l(U)$ is the Wigner-D-matrix obtained by the action of $SO(3)$ onto the space of homogeneous harmonic polynomials of degree $l$, and $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, to be thought of as a "change of basis".
Question 1: 
I suppose the matrix $Q$ is dependent on our choice of basis for the space of polynomials. Choosing the $l$-th spherical harmonics as the basis for the space of homogeneous harmonic polynomials of degree $l$, is it true that we then get $Q=\mathbb I$? 
In my mind, this seems to follow from the fact that the spherical harmonics satisfy $Y_J(U^Tx)=D_J(U)^* Y_J(x)$, see e.g. (Eq 21) in the paper.

Now to a bigger point of confusion of mine: What exactly are Clebsch-Gordan matrices and how do they relate to this representation? In the paper it is written that

"They arise in the situation where we have a tensor product of Wigner-D matrices, which as we will see is part of the equivariance constraint on the form of the equivariant kernels."

Again, let's restrict our view to polynomials of degree at most 2, i.e. $$V=\{\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2)\}\oplus \{\text{linear polynomials} \}\oplus\{\text{quadr. homogeneous harmonic polys}\},$$ then we get a representation $$\rho:SO(3)\rightarrow GL(\mathbb R^9), \rho(U)=Q^T\begin{pmatrix}D_0(U) & 0 &0 \\ 0 & D_1(U)   & 0  \\ 0 & 0 &D_2(U)\end{pmatrix}Q,$$ where $D_0(U)=1$ and $D_1(U)\in\mathbb R^{3\times 3}$ and $D_2(U)\in\mathbb R^{5\times 5}$ are the Wigner-D-Matrices for the action of $SO(3)$ onto harmonic polynomials of degree $1$ and $2$ respectively.
Question 2:
Can you give an intuitive explanation of what $Q_{l,k}$ does, perhaps by explaining what it does to a suitable basis? It is claimed that $Q_{l,k}$ again represents a change of basis. But a change from which basis to which other basis exactly? In this context, what is the intuitive meaning of the relation (Eq. 26): $$D_k(U)\otimes D_l(U)=Q_{l,k}^T \bigg[\bigoplus_{J=|k-l|}^{k+l} D_J(U)\bigg] Q_{l,k}$$
I would appreciate any insights. Thanks in advance.
